# Unable to install paper icons theme [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)] 18.04.3 XFCE

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, printing, themes

I tried installing the paper icon theme to get a better looking xfce DE after an r/unixporn post I liked however following the insructions at [this link](https://snwh.org/paper/download) returns this and I really don't know how dpkg works and what could be wrong with it, already tried rebooting, deleting the Paper folder or following a couple of commands I found googling for 
**dpkg returned an error code(1)** 
but nothing seemed to work

`ubuntu@RPi4:~$ sudo apt install paper-icon-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  paper-icon-theme
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/41.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 78.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 198269 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../paper-icon-theme_1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking paper-icon-theme (1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/paper-icon-theme_1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/Paper/cursor.theme', which is also in package paper-cursor-theme 1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/paper-icon-theme_1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

What can I do to get this theme working?

The command

> apt-cache policy paper-cursor-theme paper-icon-theme

```
    ubuntu@RPi4:~$ apt-cache policy paper-cursor-theme paper-icon-theme
    paper-cursor-theme:
      Installed: 1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1
      Candidate: 1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1
      Version table:
     *** 1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
paper-icon-theme:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     1.5.723-201905252133~daily~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy paper-cursor-theme paper-icon-theme` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got conflict between `paper-cursor-theme` and `paper-icon-theme` packages.

The [`ppa:snwh/ppa` PPA description](https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) contains the info that cursors and icons are provided with it:

> This PPA contains packages for the projects
>       from snwh.org (by Sam Hewitt) including:
>   ...
>   - Paper icon and cursor themes
>   ...

So to resolve the conflict you need to remove `paper-cursor-theme` package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove paper-cursor-theme
```

and then install `paper-icon-theme` with:

```
sudo apt-get install paper-icon-theme
```

Comment: it worked, thank you